# Vuejs - How to use a single form to add and edit

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vue-router

I'm trying to use the same component to handle the Add and Edit part of my app. I'm using Firebase, so I'm checking if there is an `id` in the route params, if there is, it renders as the edit form, if not, renders as the add form. But this doesn't work and it has some wierd behaviour.

Here is the code for the `ContactForm` component

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="card mb-3">
      <div class="card-header">{{ editing ? 'Edit' : 'Add' }} Contact</div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <form @submit.prevent="addContact">
          <TextInputGroup
            label="Name"
            name="name"
            placeholder="Enter your name..."
            v-model="contact.name"
            for="name"
          />
          <TextInputGroup
            type="email"
            label="Email"
            name="email"
            placeholder="Enter your email..."
            v-model="contact.email"
          />
          <TextInputGroup
            type="phone"
            label="Phone"
            name="phone"
            placeholder="Enter your phone number..."
            v-model="contact.phone"
          />

          <input type="submit" value="Add Contact" class="btn btn-block btn-light" />
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import TextInputGroup from "../layout/TextInputGroup";
import { db } from "../../firebase";

export default {
  components: {
    TextInputGroup
  },
  data() {
    return {
      contact: "",
      editing: false,
      email: "",
      name: "",
      phone: ""
    };
  },
  methods: {
    addContact() {
      const newContact = {
        name: this.name,
        email: this.email,
        phone: this.phone,
        createdAt: new Date()
      };
      db.collection("contacts")
        .add(newContact)
        .then(docRef => {
          console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
        });
      this.$router.push("/");
    },
    getContactById() {
      db.collection("contacts")
        .doc(this.$route.params.id)
        .get()
        .then(snapshot => {
          if (!snapshot.exists) return;
          this.contact = snapshot.data();
        });
    },
    updateContact() {
      const newContact = {
        name: this.contact.name,
        email: this.contact.email,
        phone: this.contact.phone
      };
      db.collection("contacts")
        .doc(this.$route.params.id)
        .update(newContact)
        .then(() => {
          console.log("Updated document with ID: ");
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.error("Error updating document: ", error);
        });
      this.$router.push("/");
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    if ("id" in this.$route.params) {
      this.getContactById();
      this.editing = true;
      console.log("id");
    } else {
      console.log("ups");
      // this
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

This is the [github link](https://github.com/peoray/contact-manager/) and the [live app](https://kontact-manager.netlify.com/)

Comment: Any error message in the console?

Comment: no...there is nothing

Comment: And what if you only keep the created hook? I don't think it will change anything but just trying anything that can be tried....

Comment: I don't understand, can you explain further?

Comment: You are sure there is data in your contact collection and there is no security rule that prevent reading the data?

Comment: "I don't understand, can you explain further?" You have the same code in mounted and in created. Like I said, I don't think it is the cause of the problem but I would just try with only one of these hook (i.e. "trying everything possible" mode :-)).

Comment: Not at all.
It is important to note that it kinda works...if I click on add link from the home page, it shows the appropriate input. if I click on a button to edit a contact, it works showing the data in the form, but when it's in edit mode and I can then cloick on the Add lin from the navbar, it doesn't work, it just remain the same(in edit mode)

Comment: Already removed the created hook

Comment: Can you edit the link to the app? I get 404 not found

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just cloned you repository and tested in local, **Added fixes to use single form for editing and adding**

> Here is the code for following files, just copy paste this code in below mentioned files

src/components/contact/ContactForm.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="card mb-3">
      <div class="card-header">{{ editing ? 'Edit' : 'Add' }} Contact</div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <form @submit.prevent="addContact">
          <TextInputGroup
            label="Name"
            name="name"
            placeholder="Enter your name..."
            v-model="contact.name"
            for="name"
          />
          <TextInputGroup
            type="email"
            label="Email"
            name="email"
            placeholder="Enter your email..."
            v-model="contact.email"
          />
          <TextInputGroup
            type="phone"
            label="Phone"
            name="phone"
            placeholder="Enter your phone number..."
            v-model="contact.phone"
          />

          <input type="submit" value="Add Contact" class="btn btn-block btn-light" />
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import TextInputGroup from "../layout/TextInputGroup";
import { db } from "../../firebase";

var temp = Object.freeze({
      name: '',
      email: '',
      phone: '',
    });

export default {
  components: {
    TextInputGroup
  },
  props: {
    type: {
      type: String,
      default: '',
    },
  },
  data() {
    

    return {
      contact: Object.assign({}, temp),
      editing: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    addContact() {
      this.contact.createdAt = new Date();
      db.collection("contacts")
        .add(this.contact)
        .then(docRef => {
          console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
        });
      this.$router.push("/");
    },
    getContactById() {
      db.collection("contacts")
        .doc(this.$route.params.id)
        .get()
        .then(snapshot => {
          if (!snapshot.exists) return;
          this.contact = snapshot.data();
        });
    },
    updateContact() {
      db.collection("contacts")
        .doc(this.$route.params.id)
        .update(this.contact)
        .then(() => {
          console.log("Updated document with ID: ");
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.error("Error updating document: ", error);
        });
      this.$router.push("/");
    }
  },
  created() {
    if ("id" in this.$route.params) {
      this.getContactById();
      this.editing = true;
      console.log("id");
    } else {
      console.log("ups");
      // this
    }
  },
  watch: {
    type(val) {
      if (val == 'add') {
        this.contact = Object.assign({}, temp);
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

src/components/contact/ContactItem.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="card card-body mb-3">
      <h4>
        {{ contact.name }}
        <i
          class="fas fa-sort-down pointer"
          @click="showContactInfo = !showContactInfo"
        ></i>
        <i class="fas fa-times delete right delete" @click="deleteContact(contact.id)"></i>
        <router-link :to="{path: `contact/edit/${contact.id}`, params: { id: contact.id }, query: { type: 'edit' }}">
          <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt edit right"></i>
        </router-link>
      </h4>
      <ul class="list-group" v-if="showContactInfo">
        <li class="list-group-item">Email: {{ contact.email }}</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Phone: {{ contact.phone }}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { db } from "../../firebase";

export default {
  props: {
    contact: {
      type: Object,
      required: true
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      showContactInfo: false
    };
  },
  methods: {
    deleteContact(id) {
      db.collection("contacts")
        .doc(id)
        .delete()
        .then(function() {
          console.log("Document successfully deleted!");
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.error("Error removing document: ", error);
        });
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.pointer {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.right {
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
}

.edit {
  color: black;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

.delete {
  color: red;
}
</style>
```

src/components/layout/Navbar.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-danger mb-3 py-0">
      <div class="container">
        <a href="/" class="navbar-brand">Contact Manager</a>
        <div>
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <router-link to="/" class="nav-link">
                <i class="fas fa-home" />
                Home
              </router-link>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <router-link :to="{ path: '/contact/add', query: { type: 'add' } }" class="nav-link">
                <i class="fas fa-plus" />
                Add
              </router-link>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <router-link to="/about" class="nav-link">
                <i class="fas fa-question" />
                About
              </router-link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</template>
```

src/views/ContactForm.vue

```
<template>
  <ContactForm :type="formType" />
</template>

<script>
// @ is an alias to /src
import ContactForm from "@/components/contact/ContactForm.vue";

export default {
  name: "home",
  data() {
    return {
      formType: '',
    };
  },
  components: {
    ContactForm
  },
  watch: { 
   '$route.query.type': {
      handler: function(type) {
        this.formType = type;
      },
      deep: true,
      immediate: true
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to help. Could you please explain your code.I don't want to just copy and paste :)

Comment: Yes , when you want to add a new contact then , this.contact will have an empty form on creation , but when you have an id, that means edit, you get your this.contact prefilled with the contact based on id . Previously you were having name, email, phone globally in this component instead of only rely on this.contact. Now I have refactored to share this form for both add and edit . Do you have any other clarifications ? , if not do accept and upvote this answer

Comment: Also, the problem seems to remain. Try clicking on the edit icon to make the form show as edit mode, then try to click the **Add** link from the navbar, you'll notice despite the URL has changed, it still remains in the edit mode

Comment: I understand your explanation but it doesn't solve the issue. It was working before though, my form gets prefilled when I click on the **Edit icon** from the homepage. The main issue is getting the right form to render correctly as stated above

Comment: That is the logic you have written, add else block , if no id is present, it should reset the this.contact object

Comment: Inside else block in created hook this.contact = Object.freeze({ name:  ‘’,email: ‘’’, phone: ‘’ })

Comment: Still the same behaviour, I did add the code you wrote above but nothing changed. You mentioned you cloned the app, does it work for you?

Comment: I've added a props to child contact form component and added a watcher to parent component and made it worked. let me know if your are free, we can discuss more on it

Comment: I'm free now. Can you elaborate more on what you did, also, if you could put the updates you made to this answer so I can mark it

Comment: It's not. But I feel maybe there is something I'm missing from yours. Please, do you mind looking over my code?
https://github.com/peoray/contact-manager/

Comment: You have missed adding “type” in contactForm component props

Comment: Also you have missed adding data property in contactForm in views folder , just copy paste and replace the entire file give above . You have missed out many changes from the above code

Comment: It finally worked! Please, could you go over the code, the new additions you made, some parts are not clear to me especially the watch in ContacForm in the views folder

Comment: Read about vue life cycle. If a component is created in the ui but again you are trying to create the same component on url changes. Vue just creates once in this case and only edit works fine. When you are in edit and click on add in navbar does not trigger created hook in contact form . But you can pass props from parent to child to update contact form. If url changes this.$route.query it has edit or add as value if changes it passes as props to child where it was mounted. Added another watcher in child to listen for add action